# Java one-time use wrapping class

Tags: java, json

I'm using Data Access Layer/Object (DAL/DAO) pattern, and I am constructing a Request object to be sent to the back-end (note: I have no control over the back-end's design). The Request object looks something like this:

```
class DAORequest {

    private Integer field1;
    private String field2;
    private AttrList field3;
    ...
    private Long fieldn;

}
```

where `AttrList` class is:

```
class AttrList {

    private List<Attr> attributes; // this is the only field of AttrList class  

}
```

(On the side note: I'm conforming to a JSON-format request that looks like this:

```
request {

    field1: value1,
    field2: value2,
    attrList: {
        attributes: [{}, {}, ..., {}]
    },
    ...
}
```

the Java object will be converted to GSON/JSON request)

I'm quite loathe to write another class (`AttrList` in my case) whose sole purpose is to wrap the actual content (and by consequence, would clutter my project space with un-reusable java files). Actually, there are many more RESTful endpoints in the back-end whose Requests are to be built this way. Is there anyway I can avoid writing `AttrList` and the like?

Comment: Here your class AttrList will be same as Envelop in JSON. So if you think data in attrList is of different matter than the other data (i.e. field1, field2..), you can use this. or else remove envelop.

Comment: You mean you want to avoid creating a class and follow the same solution for all other needs?

Comment: @Hichamov Actually, it's more of avoiding to write another .java file.

Comment: @prtk_shah How do you `this.` or that envelope thingie? Can you show a sample code?

Comment: Are you using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/)? Because if not, it will be only a matter of annotations and a small marshaling/unmarshaling method

Comment: @Hichamov I'm not using Jackson (and I don't think it's part of project requirement or rather, I'm not sure if our client going to accept additional libraries to use). At most, we use google.gson libraries.

Comment: Then it should be easy with gson, you'll juste write a utility method to [deserialise](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)

Comment: try this : http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#envelope